# Is int main(int, char const* const*) well formed?

Tags: c++, c++11

According to the C++11 standard, is the following program well-formed and portable C++?

```
int main(int argc, char const* const* argv) {}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No. In a pure portable C++ program, the `argv` argument, if present, has no `const` modifiers.

**Edit:** See section 3.6.1.2 of the C++11 draft standard, which (in the version I have before me) states:

> An implementation shall not predefine the main function. This function
>   shall not be overloaded. It shall have a return type of type int, but
>   otherwise its type is implementation-defined. All implementations
>   shall allow both of the following definitions of main:
>
> `int main(){ /*...*/ }`
>
> and
>
> `int main(int argc, char* argv[]) { /* ...  */ }`

Answer (score 3):

Depends on what you mean by portable. An evil C++ implementation could reject it on the grounds that its signature, `int(int,char const*const*)`, is different from one of the required allowed signatures, `int()` and `int(int,char**)`. (An evil implementation could seemingly reject `auto main(int argc,char* argv[]) -> int` or, indeed, any definition of `main` where the body isn't `{ /* ... */ }`)

However this isn't typical. I don't know of any implementations where adding a const would cause a problem calling `main`, and since C++11 added the bit about 'similar' types you won't violate the strict aliasing rule when accessing a `char**` object through a `char const * const *` variable.

So while a conforming implementation could technically reject it, I think it will be portable to any implementation you might care to use.

Comment: Gosh, I didn't realise that adding similar types to the legal aliases was intended to enable functions whose supplied arguments and formal parameters have mis-matched types ;-) But yes, it'll probably just work (TM).

Comment: @SteveJessop It's not intended to enable that, and in fact doesn't enable that in general because adding `const` to a formal parameter will affect name mangling. The reason this works for `main` is because `main` is typically exempt from mangling (because you're not allowed to overload main anyway). The addition of similar types only means that you don't automatically get undefined behavior for violating the strict aliasing rule when you access a `char**` as a `char const * const *`. It worked fine before C++11 on all implementations I know of, but it was technically UB. Now it shouldn't be UB

Comment: Do you happen to have a source or standard quote on `auto main(int argc,char* argv[]) -> int` being a different signature?  Is `int main(int argc, char** argv)` not also a different signature then?

Comment: @AntonGolov: I think the standard is notoriously fuzzily-worded here. All it says is that those two *definitions* of `main` are allowed. It doesn't say those two parameter lists, or those two signatures, which is why you can even facetiously argue (as bames53 does) that the body must be `/* ... */`. However, the previous sentence talks about the *type* of main, and the type of a function declared `auto main(int, char**) -> int` is the same as the type of one of the examples given. I'd say that in a sensible reading of the standard, any `main` with the same signature as either example is OK.

Comment: @bames53: I was joking, but if name-mangling is the only remaining obstacle then you can always use `extern "C"`. Then declaring any function incorrectly in another TU, and calling it using a prototype with `char **` when it is defined `char const *const`, is about as likely to work as this thing with `main` is. I wouldn't advise it though, I think the "right" thing to do if you want const-qualified `argv` is just to write `int main(int argc, char **argv) { return my_main(argc, argv); }` and define `my_main` with the const. Do a conversion, even if similar types don't actually need one.